# orthogonal complement of the linear span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am going back through old problems, and I still can't figure this one out.

Find an orthonormal basis for the orthogonal complement of the linear span of the vectors $(1,0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,-1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

So I understand what a orthonormal basis is, but how do you take the orthogonal complement of the linear span?  Is it the linear span of the orthogonal complements of the components? i.e. $(1,0,1,0)^\perp$ and $(1,0,-1,0)^\perp$

Comment: It's the vector space where each vector is orthogonal to the vector of the linear span of the vector given in the question, but you can think as the vector that are both orthogonal to $(1,0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,-1,0)$.

Comment: So I'm correct?  I just need to find a vector for $(1,0,1,0)^\perp$ and $(1,0,-1,0)^\perp$?  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the vector of the linear span of the vector".

Comment: @DiegoMath - Your edit makes sense.  Just to confirm, I need to find vectors are that perp to both of the vectors in the linear span.  Would $(0,1,0,1),(0,-1,0,-1)$ satisfy the question?  I just want to make sure that I fully grasp the solution.

Comment: There are more simpler vector to take instead... Think a little, you want vectors such that $\langle(x,y,z,w),(1,0,\pm1,0)\rangle=0$, so, what are the conditions over $x,y,z,w$?

Comment: So I could also take any two vectors such that $x=-z$ and $x=z$?

Comment: Yes, but note that $x=-z$ and $x=z$ implies $x=z=0$.